# Regex - Quantity Field

Tags: javascript, regex, integer

I want to validate the contents of a quantity field using Javascript's Regular Expressions.

Valid input would be an integer number, from zero upwards. If leading zeros could be removed too that would be great.

**Examples**

```
1         Pass
0         Pass
01        Failed
00        Failed
-1        Failed
1.1       Failed
1000000   Pass
```

I have tried myself, but the best I got was...

```
var regex = /[0-9]{1,9}/;
```

...which doesn't fail on negative numbers, or numbers with leading zeros.

Thanks!

Comment: 01 is a valid >= 0 integer number, as well as 00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regular expression matches any sequence of digits without a leading `0` (except for `0` itself, which is handled separately).

```
var regex = /^0$|^[1-9][0-9]*$/;
```

`^` and `$` are anchors, which anchor the match to the beginning and end of the string. This means, nothing is allowed before or after the number, and as such, no minus can be included.

Comment: Perfect. I knew you stackoverflow guys wouldn't let me down!

Comment: how to use it with "replace()" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **remove** leading zeros instead of forbidding them, then you can use this:

```
^0*(\d{1,9})$
```

Now you will find the number without trailing zeros in captured group no. `1` (even if only one `0` was entered).

Answer (score 0):

Try `^\d+$`. Should match positive integers.

Comment: This will match 01 for example

Comment: Doesn't handle leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /^0*([^0]\d*)$/;
var match = re.exec(str);
if (match) {
    var i = parseInt(match[1], 10);
}
else {
    //whoops, not an integer
}
```

(match[1] returns the int without leading zeroes, match[0] the entire matched string).

Comment: This will not handle `0` by itself, will it?

Comment: Bah. If you change it to parseInt(match[0], 10) it will. The regex itself will match 0.

Comment: No it will not. It requires one non-zero character ;)